# how to build rails api with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I know nothing about PostgreSQL and a little about Ruby on Rails. I know Ruby. I have experience with the command line.

I'm interning and I was told to build a Rails API that loads data into a two-dimensional array from PostgreSQL database. The API is meant to have methods to get certain pieces of the data given a certain index.

I don't know how/where to begin despite how simple it should be. I have no experience with databases. Please point me in the right direction to get this set up and started.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with Rails 5, you can generate a Rails API only application. Just use the following command:

```
rails new project-name-here --api --database=postgresql
```

I assume that you have ruby, rails and postgresql installed.

```
rails db:create # creating DB
```

Running `rails generate scaffold User first_name:string last_name:string`, it will generate all files needed for `User` model.

> A [scaffold](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate) in Rails is a full set of model, database migration for
>   that model, controller to manipulate it, views to view and manipulate
>   the data, and a test suite for each of the above.

```
rails db:migrate # migrating the DB
rails s # starting the server
```

Now, you can access the `/users` endpoint. Do not forget to update controllers actions with relevant data.

[A detailed example](https://blog.codeship.com/building-a-json-api-with-rails-5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) gem for building API. They provide a good [documentation](http://intridea.github.io/grape/docs/index.html) also.

[Here](http://funonrails.com/2014/03/building-restful-api-using-grape-in-rails/) is a tutorial for building API with grape.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rails-api gem. This gem has very helpful documentation but still if you need help, you can ask me in comments.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know where to start. All the Rails tutorials I've found are for use in a website and I can't seem to figure out how to adapt it for just a RESTful API which shouldn't be that complex.  All it needs is load from database and then output JSON data formatted by the API.